# Evaluate $[L:\mathbb {Q}]$, where $L$=Gal$(x^4-2,\mathbb{Q})$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Please, give-me a hint to solve this question.

"Evaluate $[L:\mathbb {Q}]$, where $L$=Gal$(x^4-2,\mathbb{Q})$".

Solution: Gal$(x^4-2,\mathbb{Q})=\mathbb{Q}[\alpha,u]$, where $\alpha=\sqrt[4]{2}$ and $u=\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{4}\right)$+i.$sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{4} \right)= i $.

Since $x^4-2$ is an irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\alpha$ is a root, it follows that $[\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]:\mathbb{Q}]=4$. Now note that  $x^4-1=(x^2+1)(x^2-1)$, i.e., $(x^2-1)$ is an irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$ which has $u$ as a root. As a consequence, $[\mathbb{Q}[u]:\mathbb{Q}]=2$. As gcd$\{2,4\}\neq 1$, I can't simply conclude that $[L:\mathbb{Q}]=2.4=8$. Any help is welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $gcd(2,4) \neq 1$ you can't conclude, you are right, but you can argue by using the fact that $i \notin \mathbb{R}$. You have

$\begin{equation*}
[\mathbb{Q}[\alpha,u]:\mathbb{Q}] = [\mathbb{Q}[\alpha,u]:\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)][\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}]
\end{equation*}$

The last one, as you said, is 4. Now, you can use the fact that $i$ is a root of $x^2-1$, which you can think in $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$, hence $[\mathbb{Q}[\alpha,u]:\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)] \leq 2$. Now, since $i$ is not a real number, it can't be $1$ (in this case $i$ would be in $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$, which is included in the real numbers). Hence you must have that this degree is 2, and the result follows.

Comment: Yes; you know that $[\mathbb{Q}[\alpha,u]:\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]]$ is the degree of the min. poly. of $u$ over $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$: since the polynomial $x^2 - 1 \in \mathbb{Q}[x] \subseteq \mathbb{Q}[\alpha][x]$ has $u$ as a root, the min. poly. of $u$ must divide it (since it is the minimum, the irreducible one: in fact, one has that if we denote $p(x)$ the min. poly. of $u$ over $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$ and $f(x)$ is ANY polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$ such that f(u) = 0, then $p(x)$ MUST divide $f(x)$). Hence its degree must be less or equal than 2.

Comment: Hello, Klaramun! I didn't understand very well why it must be $[\mathbb{Q}[\alpha,u]:\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]]\le 2$. Could you explain it in more detail?

Comment: Excelent explanation! A final question, please. Is it correct to say that $\{1,\alpha,\alpha^2,\alpha^3\}$ is a basis for $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$, $\{1,u\}$ is a basis for $\mathbb{Q}[u]$ and a basis for $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha,u]$ is the multiplication of these two basis by using distributivity?

Comment: $\{1,\alpha,\alpha^2,\alpha^3\}$ is a basis of $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$ as a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space.

$\{1,u\}$ is a basis of $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha,u]$ as a $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$-vector space.

So, a $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha,u]$ as a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space is just the product of the elements, that is $\{1,\alpha,\alpha^2,\alpha^3,u,u\alpha,u\alpha^2,u\alpha^3\}$, which has 8 elements, as we know (degree 8).